# How to add data multiple nested lists of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, object

In this example, i am able to create new student object and able to add data to its 2 variables called Id and Name but i am facing difficulty and not able to add third variable (List -> i.e. friends)

```
using System;
using System. LINQ;
using System. Collections. Generic;

public class Program
{
   //public List<Student> students;
    public static void Main()
    {
        var students = new List<Student>();
        students. Add(new Student
        {
           Id = 120228,
           Name = "Rajesh",
        });
        students. Add(new Student
        {
           Id = 120229,
           Name = "Mahesh",
        });
    
        foreach(var student in students)
            Console. WriteLine(student.Id + ", " +student.Name);
    }
}

public class Student
{ 
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<Friend> friends;
}

public class Friend {
    public int friendId;
    public string friendName;
}
```

How should i add data to "friends"(List<Friend>) variable like other first 2 fields. (if possible help me with working code)

```
//finally, i want to print all details of the student.

foreach(var student in students){
      foreach(var friend in student.friends){
          Console. WriteLine(student.Name+ " friend name is " +friend.Name);
      }
}
```

Thank you for your valuable time!!

Comment: Wild assume, you probably get an `NullReferenceException` on field `friends`?

Comment: You've not initialised `List<Friend> friends` anywhere I can see. Either do it in the constructor for `Student`, or do it somewhere else once you've created the `Student` object

Answer (score 3):

Before you can add friends, you need to instantiate the friendlist first. This can be done inline like this:

```
students.Add(new Student
{
   Id = 120229,
   Name = "Mahesh",
   friends = new List<Friend>
   {
        new Friend
        {
            friendId = 10,
            friendName = "John"
        },
        new Friend
        {
            friendId = 11,
            friendName = "Jane"
        },
   }
});
```

But if you want to add friends after construction of a new Student. You need to instantiate the list before adding friends:

```
var student = new Student
{
    Id = 120229,
    Name = "Mahesh",
};

// instantiate the friendslist before adding an item.
student.friends = new List<Friend>();

student.friends.Add(new Friend
{
    friendId = 10,
    friendName = "John"
});
```

Normally I would choose to construct the friendlist inside the student, because you probably add new friends later. The problem is, otherwise you need to check if the `friends` field is not assigned(not instantiate) and you have to create it:

```
public class Student
{ 
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();
}


var student = new Student
{
    Id = 120229,
    Name = "Mahesh",
};

// instantiate the friendslist before adding an item.
student.friends.Add(new Friend
{
    friendId = 10,
    friendName = "John"
});
```

---

*A tip: Note the code writing conventions. The Student Id/Name uses PascalCase, but the friends and Friend class fields are using camelCase. Try use the same casing of existing code, otherwise it will become a mess.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and clear-cut explanation!!!,

Comment: Surely, will follow the conventions